# Laravel 5.2 Password reset not working

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2 and basically almost have a final version of my app...give client to test and he informs me the password reset isn't working and unfortunately he is correct...my problem is that when I try to reset password for a particular user it does absolutely nothing...no errors nothing...just basically thinks for a bit and reloads the page although the email address i put in remains there...

I just dont really know where to go from here?

I have looked at laravel.log in storage/logs but I cant see anything useful in there...

I do have email set up correctly as I use it as another part of my app and its working fine but I am putting my own email address in and receiving nothing...

At this point I guess I am just looking for debugging tips as I have exhausted all other options and have no idea where to look...

Any Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Take debugger and debug your code?

Comment: im kinda new to php but all ive been using for debugging so far is dd($var) and using errors provided by laravel/php...after that im stuck and I dont have any errors at the moment and have no idea where to dd as I didn't actually write the password reset...its automagically generated by laravel...my guess is I just broke it along the way...I just have no idea where...

Comment: you said you checked the storage/logs folder, what about your actual http logs? Also since it is done all through Laravel's "Magic" try putting `APP_DEBUG=true` in your .env maybe that will shed some light.. Also `composer dump` might help.. never hurts to try

Comment: I have set APP_DEBUG=true already....never even heard of http logs...do you mean my php logs? composer dump doesnt do much although im not entirely sure what it does? Is it actually dumping something somewhere? II read somewhere online it does something with the classes?

Comment: Verify that you print out $errors on the password reset page. Then you should start looking up the trait which actually runs the reset. Verify you end up where the mail is being sent ( just dd($var) some vars to do so ). Afterwards verify sending mails as working at all. Maybe you changed the email column of the users table to mail or something?

Comment: same issue here did you find any solutions?

Comment: Yeah...I just ended up (very reluctantly) running the make:auth command again and it seemed to fix it and didn't break anything else...highly recommend committing or even creating a new branch for this if you are going to try it...its kinda annoying that that was the answer for me as i was pulling my hair out over it for days haha